# Direct sound from speakers (output) to mic (input)

Tags: speakers, microphone

This is an attempt make Skype and Ventrilo more fun/easier. I'm essentially looking for a method/hardware/application that does essentially the same thing as me physically moving my speakers to beside my mic, for others in voice chat to listen.

I'm using W7, but use OSX too, so interested in both.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into cheap software for pirating music...it will do this.  virtualloopback comes to mind

Comment: Interesting, thanks. A loopback on *nix might work, but I'm not sure which software on W7 is going to work. Wouldn't the that software output mp3/wmv files? That wouldn't be live from speakers device TO mic device? Sorry, I can't find anything with this answer yet.

Comment: On windows 7 MS started requiring vendors to disable hijacking speaker output...I don'r remember the thread, bit I posted a link somewhere on SU about this very issue already.  The only options are writing/finding a virtual sound driver and getting a cert to sign it as an approved driver.  This way, MS can say we think it will be used for pirating music and push a certificate revocation out of band....just my opinion...probably why you can't find it.  there was one floating around a while back, but it disappeared.

Comment: maybe http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm