# Windows 8.1: Making the "Microphone In" record your sound-out without using a mic

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

So, I want to play my sound into teamspeak for a "music chat".

What I need to do is get my sound-in to be what is coming out of my speakers.

I have tried googling this in several different ways, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable software tool to pipe sound output to microphone input](http://superuser.com/q/346593/150988), [How to record sound directly from output?](http://superuser.com/q/640317/150988),
[Direct sound from speakers (output) to mic (input)](http://superuser.com/q/218488/150988),
[Stream PC audio to Skype](http://superuser.com/q/645753/150988), [How to create a virtual audio device and stream audio input with it](http://superuser.com/q/117625/150988),
and maybe also [What's the reason behind “Stereo Mix” becoming a missing option?](http://superuser.com/q/299082/150988)

Comment: @Scott Did you look at the answer to the one you marked as duplicate when you flagged the question? *"look into cheap software for pirating music...it will do this. virtualloopback comes to mind"* is the only answer. Some of the other duplicates you listed are much better, but the initial one was not very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your soundcard, but usually this is a yes.

You need to select your soundcard as recording device, and from the soundcard mixer, set it to record the wave or "what you hear".

Most recent soundcards can do this, but not all.

If you do not have this option, there is an alternative.

Buy a male-jack to male-jack audio cable and plug it in from the audio-out to the line-in. Your audio is now routed from your speakers out to the line in, and you can put that into teamspeak. The only downside with this is that you cannot hear any sound yourself unless you connect to teamspeak from a different pc.

Comment: Hey thank you.
I'll just cable it together, since I have 2 pc's I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but if you have a Y-splitter you can actually have 2 outputs out of the same jack, one will go into the input jack, the other will connect to your speakers.

The downside: splitting the signal in 2 sources will reduce volume of original sound in half, so let's say the jack was giving out 12 dbs of loudness, now each side will give 6 dbs. If you got good speakers you can just raise the volume to hear what you need, no problem, since all you do is amplifying the sound output.

That's what speakers do essentially, they amplify the line level signal. But that's another conversation.